# PowerShell set XML value #text

Tags: xml, powershell, text

I try to set the value of an element. It it is not empty in my XML, it works, but if it is empty, is doesn't work.

My XML:

```
...
<Field IDREF="934d80f1" Name="FirstName">works</Field>
<Field IDREF="936845ba" Name="LastName"></Field>
...
```

If I write the contents with

```
$record.BusinessObject.FieldList.Field | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $field }
```

it returns

```
IDREF           Name                        #text
-----           ----                        -----
934d80f1        FirstName                   works
```

And in the second row the "virtual" Attribute #text is missing:

```
IDREF           Name
-----           ----
936845ba        LastName
```

with the PowerShell code

```
record.BusinessObject.FieldList.Field | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $field } | ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = $state }
```

I want to set the value >VALUE< of the selected element. It doesn't work if the value is empty...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `$_.InnerXml` property, and it will set the value on the required field.

```
$record.BusinessObject.FieldList.Field | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -eq $field
} | ForEach-Object {
  $_.InnerXml = $state
}
```